# Delete empty rows using parser in Aeroo Reports

Tags: python, xml, odoo, aeroolib

I created an .odt form document file which fills in variables in each cell of the form (with a table layout). I created input field with reference values This is the kind of value I fill in under the reference of the input field/cell: `<o.o_xml_orbeon.xml.orthopedischebinnenschoenenobvksectie.bspolsteringachillespeeslinks.select.labels>`

This value is variable because it selects the selected label of a radio button selection of an xml form.

This all works for all input fields with different references and when exporting it to PDF it all works fine.

My question now: how can I delete those empty rows using the parser python code in OpenERP?

The parser code I have right now is this:

```
class Parser(report_sxw.rml_parse):
    def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context):
        super(Parser, self).__init__(cr, uid, name, context)
        self.localcontext.update({})
```

[image: code in OpenERP environemt]

The .odt table form looks like this (veldwaarde = field value, the 'input field'):
[image]
How can I loop through the form and remove the rows that are empty after mapping the referenced value in the cells?